# Creating appointment with c# using EWS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, calendar, exchangewebservices

I want to create an program which makes it able to create an appointment in someone else's outlook calendar. for example : If someone asks 5 days free at his boss, the boss needs to be able to approve it and immediately make it visible in the person's outlook calendar. I tried making a code with EWS but i always get this error:[image]
*An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
Additional information: Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to*

here is my code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace exchangetest
{
public partial class Test1 : Form
{

    public Test1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username@domain.com", "password");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@domain.com");
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

        // Set the properties on the appointment object to create the appointment.
        appointment.Subject = "Tennis lesson";
        appointment.Body = "Focus on backhand this week.";
        appointment.Start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
        appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddHours(1);
        appointment.Location = "Tennis club";
        appointment.ReminderDueBy = DateTime.Now;

        // Save the appointment to your calendar.
        appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);

        // Verify that the appointment was created by using the appointment's item ID.
        Item item = Item.Bind(service, appointment.Id, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Subject));
    }
}
}
```

I really hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Copy/Paste the error you are getting to let others find your solution once it will be answered. Images are not indexed.

Comment: Have you tried setting the URL of the service directly, instead of using AutoDiscover?

Comment: I did try to add the URL manually, but perhaps i did it wrong. If i want to login on [link](https://login.live.com/) should I i use https://login.live.com/ as domain? anyway i got the same error code.

Comment: Please post the complete error message as text, you have stopped in the middle. And also please the code as text where the error happens. Then you can remove the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the AutoDiscoverURL overload the allows you to specify a callback validation eg

```
     service.AutodiscoverUrl("username@domain.com",adAutoDiscoCallBack);

        internal static bool adAutoDiscoCallBack(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        bool result = false;

        Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }

        return result;

    }
```

Office365 always does a redirect so something like this is needed you can put in more validation code to make it more secure to prevent man in the middle attacks etc by validating the server name etc.

Cheers
Glen